# Finding neighbouring countries using Overpass?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, adjacency, overpass-turbo

How can I find all countries that are neighbours (share a border point or line) of a given country (eg. germany) using Overpass?

Comment: Is this a one off activity, or do you want to integrate this in some app and run it on a regular basis by many users? This kind of analysis is very expensive, and I don't want to post something that will create too much load on public instances. Also, what exactly do you mean by neighbors? Would Russia be a neighbor of the US?

Comment: I'm interested in the syntax in the first place. The query will be extended to neighbouring regions or states in the next step. Results will be cached forever, since I don't need to track future changes. By neighbours I mean countries that share a border line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for overpass turbo is as follows (the example deliberately uses admin_level=4 which will return "Bundesländer", rather than neighboring countries to keep the data volume small. If you want neighboring countries you need to adjust the admin level).

```
is_in({{center}});
area._[boundary=administrative][admin_level=4];
rel(pivot);way(r);node(w);
is_in;
area._[boundary=administrative][admin_level=4];
rel(pivot);
out geom;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to control the output? I changed the output to json (using `[out:json]` in the first line) and the query output to meta (using `out meta;` in the last line) but still get a lot more data than necessary. I'm basically only interested in the name and pivot coordinates of each result. Skipping all the "way" nodes would already be a huge plus.

Comment: Try replacing  `out geom;`  by `out center tags;`

Comment: Very nice, thank you for the help!